# Uploading files to a bluemix app and pointing to them from configuration files

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I am trying to upload files to my bluemix app and I am having problems using and understanding the file system. After I have succesfully uploaded files I want to give their path on my configuration files.

Specifically, I want to upload a `jar` file to the server and later use it as javaagent.

I have tried approaching this isuue from several directions.
I see that I can create a folder in the liberty_buildpack and place the files inside I can later access it on the compilation-release phases from the tmp folder:

```
/tmp/buildpacks/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/lib/liberty_buildpack/my_folder
```

Also I can see that in the file system that I see when building and deploying the app I can copy only to the folder located in:

```
/app
```

So I copied the JAR file to the app file and set it as a javaagent using 2 method:

1. Manually set enviorment variable JAVA_OPTS with java agent to point to /app/myjar.jar using `cf set-env`
2. Deploy a war file of the app using `cf push` from wlp server and set the java agent inside the `server.xml` file and attribute `genericJvmArguments`

Both of those methods didnt work, and either the deploy phase of the application failed or my features simply didnt work.

So I tried searching the application file system using `cf files` and came up with the `app` folder, but strangly it didn't have the same file as the folder I deploy and I couldn't find any connection to the deployed folder ot the build pack.

Can someone explain how this should be done correctly? namely, uploading the file and then how should I point to it from the enviorment variable/server file?
I mean should it be /app/something or maybe other path?
I have also seen the use of relative paths like `@droplet.sandbox` maybe its the way to address those files? and how should I access those folders from `cf files`

Thanks.

EDIT:
As I have been instructed in the comments I have added the jar file to the system, the problem is that when I add the javaagent variable to the enviorment variable JAVA_OPTS the deploy stage fails with the timeout error:
payload: {... "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>32, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>
1433864527}

The way I am assigning the javaagent is as follows:

```
cf set-env myApp JAVA_OPTS "path/agent.jar"
```

I have tried adding several location:
 1. I have found that if I add the jar files to my WebContent folder I can find it in: /app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/myapp.war/resources/
 2. I have copied the jar file from the /tmp location in the compilation phase to /home/vcap/app/agent.jar
 3. I have located the jar file in /app/.java/jre/lib

none of those 3 paths worked.
I found out that if I give a wrong path the system behaves the same so it may be a path problem. 
Any ideas?

Comment: In the value of JAVA_OPTS, you need to add "-javaagent:". The app crashes probably because you are not specifying the java options correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Put your agent jars in a folder called ".profile.d" inside your WAR package;
2. cf se your-app JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/home/vcap/app/.profile.d/your.jar ;
3. Push the war to Bluemix.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer, I did it and I have a weird problem, when i show the file tree using cf files I dont get /home as one of the results in the root directory. I get the following result:
.bash_logout                              220B
.bashrc                                   3.0K
.profile                                  675B
app/                                         -
logs/                                        -
run.pid                                     3B
staging_info.yml                          299B
tmp/                                         -

Comment: Yes you cannot browse outside of the "/home/vcap" folder. "cf files" starts with "/home/vcap" as the root folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I wrote my problem in the EDIT section of the question can you please refer to it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly the right answer, but I am using additional jar files in my Liberty application, so maybe this will help.

I push up a `myapp.war` file to bluemix. Within the war file, inside the `WEB-INF` folder, I have a `lib` folder that contains a number of jar files. The classes in those jar files are then used within the java code of my application.

```
myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/myPlugin.jar
```

You could try doing something like that with the jar file(s) you need, building them into the war file.

Other than that, you could try the section `Overlaying the JRE` from the bluemix [liberty documentation](https://www.stage1.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#customizingjre) to add jars to the JRE.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I wrote my problem in the EDIT section of the question can you please refer to it?